# How to call a generic method from c# in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojureclr

I have a generic method in c# like `UseStartup<Startup>` in c# and i want to use it in clojureclr,
now i have create a ns like

```
(ns myapp.startup
(gen-class
:name myapp.Startup))
```

but i wonder how to pass it to the c# generic method